# Ionic 3 Plunker with SCSS not working

Tags: css, sass, ionic3, plunker

I have found that [**this plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/cpeRJs?p=preview) is using for Ionic 3.X demo by the Ionic team.But can you tell me how to add `.scss` file to that.Let's say I need to add `app/home.page.scss` or may be a global `scss` file.Can you help me for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xeskvU4PNPNh7q1DWWNe?p=preview)

Following are the changes that I made:

1) created app/home.page.scss

2) Added following meta data in app/home.page.ts

```
styleUrls: ['app/home.page.scss']
```

3) Added class red in app/home.page.html

`<ion-title class="red">{{ appName }}</ion-title>`

4) Added following in app/home.page.scss

```
.red {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

I hope this is what you needed !

Comment: This is exactly what I need.Thank you so much :)

Comment: Glad it helped. :)